# IdentityServer4 with persistent database

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm trying to use IdentityServer4 with persistent database. I have an Oracle db. I'm planning on Extending the `ConfigurationDbContext` and `PersistedGrantDbContext` in order to do some oracle specific customization.

**PersistedGrantDbContext**

```
 public class IdentityPersistedGrantDbContext : PersistedGrantDbContext {
    public IdentityPersistedGrantDbContext(DbContextOptions<PersistedGrantDbContext> options, OperationalStoreOptions storeOptions)
         : base(options, storeOptions) {
    }
}
```

**ConfigurationDbContext**

```
public class IdentityConfigurationDbContext : ConfigurationDbContext {
    public IdentityConfigurationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext> options, ConfigurationStoreOptions storeOptions)
         : base(options, storeOptions) {
    }
}
```

In the startup class, I do I tell the IdentityServer to use the custom classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `IPersistedGrantStore` as seen [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/2f1cc69a06d1fafea99fc53499dbd02c55763f22/src/IdentityServer4/Stores/IPersistedGrantStore.cs). And add it to the ASP.NET Core ServiceCollection (aka the DI container).

eg:

```
        services.AddTransient<IPersistedGrantStore, MyPersistedGrantStore>();
```

where MyPersistedGrantStore uses that DbContext to do those CRUD operations as defined in the interface/contract.

Comment: How can I validate a user with userame and pwd.

Answer (score 0):

It's located in IdentityServer4.EntityFramework. add a using statement for IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.DbContexts